# positive definite matrix multiplications

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be $k\times k$ positive definite matrix. $a$ is a $k\times 1$ vector, $b$ is a $k\times1$ vector and $a \neq b$.  Will $a^TAb$ still be positive?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What happens if $a=-b$?

Comment: Thanks Jose. what about when all elements in a and b are all positive, will the aTAb be positive?

Comment: Take$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix},$$$a=(1,4)$, and $b=(2,1)$. Then $a^T.A.b=-1$.